# AWS API control plane / Data Plane

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I was talking to one of my friends on talk on API access. So let us say I have given one AWS account read-only access to my resources, say ec2. And that account tries to scan all the metadata for my ec2 instances. Per my friend, this API call belongs control plane and connects to the AWS API ec2 endpoint over the internet. As per him, this call can not be blocked by any number of VPC controls like NACLs/Security Group, etc. As per him, any data plane calls only goes to VPC. I was kind of agree but still not very convinced that scanning ec2 instances call like listing all instances can not be blocked ..say I have given read-only permission and still wants to block that account ...so is this true that VPC controls do not project that call further. Please help me to understand better ...in case I am in my corporate network and my consuming account, which wants to scan my ec2 instances if SAAS provider.

Comment: Your friend is correct. Everything here is on the public Internet and can't be blocked by any VPC restrictions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html The VPC is where your servers are running and where you would block access to the ports/software running on those servers. The VPC is your private network. The AWS API is not running inside your private network, it is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Amazon EC2 *service*** is responsible for creating and managing Amazon EC2 instance, VPCs, networking, etc. The API endpoint for the EC2 *service* reside on the Internet. Permission to make API calls is controlled by AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM).

This is totally separate to the ability to *connect* to an Amazon EC2 instance. Any such connections would go via a **virtualized network VPC**.

For example, imagine **an Amazon EC2 instance that is turned off** (that is, in a Stopped state). There are no actual resources assigned to a Stopped instance -- it is just some metadata sitting in a database. It would not be possible to 'connect' with this instance because it does not exist. However, it *would* be possible to connect to the AWS EC2 *service* and issue a command to Start the instance. This API call is made via the Internet and does not require any connectivity to the VPC.

Your wording that "any data plane calls only goes to VPC" is not correct -- the calls go to the EC2 *service* and do not involve the VPC. The VPC is purely a network configuration that determines how resources can communicate with each other.